# printing a range instead of individual numbers in pylab

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to get the x-axis to have ranges for the tick marks instead of just individual numbers. I take an input from a list from the user and want to divide that list in to equal parts. (`a_list` is the user input list).

This crashes as of right now.

```
import pylab
import numpy

def bar_graph(a_list):
    '''bar graph of number-frequency, xaxis labeled with ranges'''
    y_values = a_list.split(',')
    # get ticks as ranges
    bar_width=2
    x_values = numpy.arange[(max-min)/10]-1
    xvalues_ticked = x_values+bar_width/2.0
    pylab.xticks(xvalues_ticked,a_list)
    # create the bar graph
    pylab.bar(x_values,y_values,width=bar_width,color='r')
    pylab.xlabel("Ranges")
    pylab.ylabel("Frequency")
    pylab.title("Frequency of Numbers")
    pylab.plot(x_values,value_list,color='b')
    pylab.grid(True)
    pylab.show()



#Create number list

a_list = [1,5,10,20,25,55,30,70,45,15]
bar_graph(a_list)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. Could you give us some more context for that line of code?

Comment: It is still really unclear what you are trying to do and this is not valid python.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess at what you are trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def bar_graph(ax, a_list):
    '''bar graph of number-frequency, xaxis labeled with ranges'''
    if isinstance(a_list, str):
        a_list = [float(_) for _ in a_list.split(',')]

    y_values = a_list
    x_values = np.arange(len(y_values)) * 2
    # get ticks as ranges
    bar_width = 2


    # create the bar graph
    ax.bar(x_values, y_values, width=bar_width, color='r', align='center')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x_values)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['{}-{}'.format(x, x+bar_width) for x in x_values])
    ax.set_xlabel("Ranges")
    ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
    ax.set_title("Frequency of Numbers")
    ax.plot(x_values, y_values, color='b')
    ax.grid(True)




a_list = [1,5,10,20,25,55,30,70,45,15]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar_graph(ax, a_list)
```

[image]